# How to tell ssh to connect through fortinet vpn tunnel

Tags: ssh, vpn, forticlient

I need a VPN and SSH tunnel to connect from my home PC to my workstation. Since I am the only one using Linux in my company, the following solution is the best my IT department has to offer:

My computer with Manjaro Linux

- Virtual machine with a Windows 10 guest system
- Fortinet VPN Client connection to [work1]
- Remote Desktop (RDP) connection to a computer in the company
- PuTTY SSH connection to [work2]
- Calling the work web page in the browser.

Now I am on my own to optimize the connection. Obviously I want to avoid the virtual machine and remote desktop connection, my goal looks like this:

My computer with Manjaro Linux

- VPN connection to [work1] with `openfortivpn`.
- SSH connection to [work2]
- Calling the work web page in my local browser

The VPN connection with [openfortivpn (github)](https://github.com/adrienverge/openfortivpn) is already running, but I get a timeout on the SSH connection.

I suspect it is because SSH is not using the VPN tunnel for the connection, because also my browser is not using the vpn tunnel, my public ip address on *ifconfig.me* remains the same. However my network knowledge is too poor to know how to check this.

[work1] and [work2] are separate servers at two different physical locations. I can ping both [work1] and [work2] at any time, regardless of whether the vpn tunnel to [work1] is up or not.

Comment: How are work1 and work2 connected - is work2 a server inside the main work network, or a remote/public address? Can you ping the server? Does the server allow connections from work1's vpn network?

Comment: You mentioned this is a connection to your workplace. It would be best to consult your companies IT department.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I re-wrote the question to make it more clear. Unfortunately my IT department is of no use in this case.

Comment: Why do you need the Windows 10 guest OS? To use the Fortinet? That seems ridiculous. The `openfortivpn` seems to partially work. The best advice would be to talk to your company’s IT department to get specific settings to use. Or perhaps just use an [official Fortinet client like the ones here](https://www.fortinet.com/support/product-downloads/linux). Unfamiliar if anything there can be used with Manjaro Linux, but something might work since Manjaro and Arch are Debian-based.

Comment: Yes it is ridiculous, I am using `openfortivpn` on Manjaro now which works great. Also `Remmina` for the RDP connection works, therefore I don't need the Windows guest OS any more. Next step I would like to omit the RDP connection and set up the SSH connection directly from my local computer.

Comment: work1 probably uses a split tunnel vpn, so only traffic directed to a work1 subnet goes through the vpn. It's usually a setting on the vpn host, and not something you can force through from the client side. Work2 most likely blocks SSH traffic from random public IPs, so you are out of luck unless either group will make changes for you. If you have admin rights to a computer at work1, you could try setting up SSH forwarding to work2, but I would **not** recommend doing so without explicit permission

Comment: @Cpt.Whale it turned out to be exactly like you described it. I'll leave it as-is for now. Thanks for your reply!